# Display image where SRC attribute of Image tag is Relative Path

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, relative-path

I have successfully upload an image to

```
C:\Users\MyComputerName\Desktop\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyWebApp\data
```

And the image name example `lala.jpg` is saved in database.

Now I am trying to display the image in my jsp.

I found that we need to create a servlet that can load file from outside of your web container and then write/stream file to your response. [One of the example is File Servlet by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.sg/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

I tried to follow but I did not able to display the image.

Can anyone point out my mistakes? Help will be appreciate. Thanks! :)

Below are my codes..

**jsp**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<c:forEach items="${staff}" var="staff">
<tr>
<td>${staff.staffName}</td>
<td><img src="FileServlet?path=C:\Users\MyComputerName\Desktop\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyWebApp\data\${staff.staffImage}"></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In **File Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get requested file by path info.
        String requestedFile = request.getParameter("path");

        System.out.println(requestedFile);

        // Decode the file name (might contain spaces and on) and prepare file object.
        File file = new File(requestedFile);

        // Get content type by filename.
        String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());

        // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
        // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
        // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

        // Prepare streams.
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }
    }

    // Helpers (can be refactored to public utility class) ----------------------------------------

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In **web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <display-name>FileServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.FileServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: kidnly add error stack

Comment: @Sureshkumar Panneerselvan That is the thing..There is no error. Furthermore, I tried to  System.out.println(requestedFile); It does not print out anything.

Comment: what does `System.out.println(requestedFile);` produce?

Comment: @user2310289 It does not produce anything.

Comment: OK that should be your question then.  Probably something to do with not encoding the string?

Comment: And what does `System.out.println("hello world");` produce? Are you sure the servlet is even called? Why don't you use a debugger to execute the code step by step? And look at your browser developer tools panel to see the sent request and the received response?

Comment: Change the file path(either relative to server or project) and debug to find where the file is loaded into servlet or not..

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan Sorry. I did not get what you meant. The file is successfully loaded to C DRIVE. Are you saying that to check if the file is successfully uploaded?

Comment: It should be either Relative to Server Context Path or Application context path.

Comment: @JBNizet It does not produce anything so the servlet is not even called. Thanks for pointing out that! There is an error. It said 404 (Not Found).

Comment: @newbieinjavaversion2: so the servlet is not properly mapped to the URL you're using, or you're using an incorrect URL in the first place.

Comment: @JBNizet I believe that I mapped my servlet correctly. I already put my web.xml at the question. Just in case. This leave to incorrect URL, I guess?

Comment: Yes. You're using a relative URL in your JSP. So, the FileServlet URL is relative to the address displayed in your address bar. If the address bar contain `http://localhost/myApp/foo/bar/baz`, then it will make a request to `http://localhost/myApp/foo/bar/FileServlet`instead of making a request to `http://localhost/myApp/FileServlet`. You'd better use absolute URLs and use the JSTL to properly generate them and encode the parameters.

Comment: Check spelling: web.xml has servlet listed as 'FileServlet'. However, you are refering to 'FileServet' on your jsp page.

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD My mistake. Sorry. I already changed. However, now the error is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\MyComputerName\Desktop\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyWebApp\data\${staff.staffImage} (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD Apparently it cannot get ${staff.staffImage. Do I need to put ' ' ?  However it does able read ${staff.staffName}.

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the image name? viz. <img src="FileServet?path=C:\Users\MyComputerName\Desktop\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyWebApp\data\lala.jpg">

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD Yes. But not ${staff.staffImage} unfortunately

Comment: It means your FileServlet is working properly. Where are you setting your 'staff' bean? Check if your staff bean is set by using EL (eg:<cout: value="${staff.staffName}")

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD Yes, I believe that FileServlet does work. I edited my question in jsp codes. Am I not using EL the right way? I am able to view Staff Name though..

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD Hi! Thanks a lot! :) I know what was my mistake. I did not properly used the EL. Once again, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right URL is:

```
<img src="FileServlet?path=C:\Users\MyComputerName\Desktop\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plug‌​ins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyWebApp\data\\<c:out value="${staff.staffImage}"/>">
```

Comment: Good that you got it working. :)
Ideally, you should not be passing whole path as parameters. Store all images in one place. Now, just send the name of image to show the image, you already know where your files are stored, don't you?